# RACSignal interval not work immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to use the RACSignal class's interval method of ReactiveCocoa.
The following code works every second after 1 seconds.
But I want it works immediately and every second.
What's the best way?

```
@weakify(self);
[[[RACSignal interval:1.0] takeUntilBlock:^BOOL(id x) {
    return [AClass count] == 0;
}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        @strongify(self);
        NSUInteger count = [AClass count];
        self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", count];
    });
}      completed:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        @strongify(self);
        self.title = @"";
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`-startWith:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/d05cd9f1fe77a8fac1960f9b09c10c5fc47baae7/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h#L175-177).

```
[[[RACSignal interval:1] startWith:NSDate.date] takeUntilBlock:^(id _) { // ...
```